# usages of "would rather" and "would prefer"

Tags: modal-verbs, stative-verbs, would-rather

> 1) I would prefer you did not mention it.
>
> 2) I would prefer you not to mention it.
>
> 3) I would rather you didn't mention it.
>
> 4)  I would rather you not to mention it.

Would you possibly show me if they are correct, if so, could you tell me if there is any difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of asking someone to not mention something, I find no difference between "I would prefer" and "I would rather". Both of them indicate a preference for the other person to keep quiet rather than mentioning something.

These leaves the second part of the phrase. My recommendation would be to use #4, except use a contraction and leave out the preposition *to*:

> **I'd rather you not mention it**.

although this wording also sounds both grammatical and natural to my native ear:

> **I'd prefer you didn't mention it**.

---

The phrase *"don't mention it"* is often used when someone is being modest or humble while  being thanked. It's similar to, "It's nothing," which is reminiscient of *de nada* in Spanish.

> "Bill, thanks for staying late last night and helping me finish that report."
>
> *"Don't mention it."*

Putting a phrase like *I'd rather* or *I would prefer* in front of "don't mention it" adds a stronger urgency to the request. I'm having a hard time imagining myself using a wording like that when dismissing a simple word of thanks – it sounds overly dramatic. Instead, I'd save the more pressing request for a situation such as trying to thwart public recognition. In other words, I'd be more likely to use it in a scenario like this one:

> "Bill, thanks for staying late last night and helping me finish that report. I'm going to have the boss give you some kudos at the next staff meeting."
>
> *"Thanks, but I'd prefer you didn't mention it."*

Comment: First off, thanks. Nevertheless, do you feel any difference between these? I would prefer you did not mention it.

2) I would prefer you not to mention it.

Comment: _prefer you not to_ rings a little awkward in my ear, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: So, are these " 'd rather not mention it and 'd rather you didn't mention it" natural?